# Failed to upload video to firebase with swift

Tags: swift, firebase, video, uikit

I'm trying to get the user to choose a video from his gallery and save it to firebase and then watch it, my code is as follows

```
    storage.child("message_videos/\(fileName)").putFile(from: fileUrl, metadata: nil, completion: { metadata, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            // failed
            print("failed to upload video file to firebase for picture")
            completion(.failure(StorageErrors.failedToUpload))
            return
        }

        self.storage.child("message_videos/\(fileName)").downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
            guard let url = url else {
                print("Failed to get download url")
                completion(.failure(StorageErrors.failedToGetDownloadUrl))
                return
            }

            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            print("download url returned: \(urlString)")
            completion(.success(urlString))
        })
    })
}
```

and ViewController Screen I understand that the app is having trouble pulling the video from the gallery but I couldn't find the reason.

```
  
 if let videoUrl = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
              let mymessageıd = "merhaba"
               let fileName = "photo_message_" + mymessageıd.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-") + ".mov"
               StorageManager.shared.uploadMessageVideo(with: videoUrl, fileName: fileName, completion: {  result in
                  
                   switch result {
                   case .success(let urlString):
                     
                       print("Uploaded  Video: \(urlString)")

                       guard let url = URL(string: urlString),
                           let placeholder = UIImage(systemName: "plus") else {
                               return
                       }
                       
                 
                           
                           let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
                           vc.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                       self.present(vc, animated: true)
                   case .failure(_):
                    print("error")
                }
    })
        }
```

Comment: What is 'firebase' and where does a guy named 'StorageManager' come from?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting questions be sure to include your code, which you did, but also include what the problem is with that code. What isn't working? Have  you done any troubleshooting; like adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code, examining the vars along the way until you spot something that isn't right? Does it crash? Are there any error messages? Please update the question with further details and we'll take a look. We also don't know what `StorageManager` is.